# sending mysql data / mysql data in .php file

Tags: php, mysql

I am submitting a project where i had to create a mysql database with tables. Everything is working on my end, so I just want to check how I can send all my zipped files to someone using a different computer. Basically, how can I create a file of my database for another computer so that all my files work correctly?... or is this even possible? edit: im using phpmyadmin btw

Thanks

Comment: You can attach a Mysql Database dump along with your project, also put some details how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using PHPmyAdmin, you may use its export-feature to get a MySQL-dump, which then can be imported on any other machine…

You may also use `mysqldump` if you have console-access.

Comment: ok, so if i use the mysql-dump and send that with my files, everything should work like i have it now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use export from your phpmyadmin and then your friend can import it in his computer.You can also see your server directory mysql/data to see the database lists.Somethimes copying from here and pasting the same way in another machine works fine

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot send them the php unless they have access to a webserver with PHP installed. You can use phpMyAdmin to export the table(s) to a variety of formats. Select a table in phpMyAdmin and click the "export" tab. Select the export type and options - it's mostly self explanatory.

Hope that answers your question :)

Answer (score 0):

With phpMyAdmin, first ensure that you are on the page for your **database** (not a specific table, otherwise it will only export that table). Click the `Export` tab, check that you have all of the tables selected,check that the "Create table if not exists" option is selected and click Go.

That will download a text file that can be imported using the import tab in phpMyAdmin.